# Building an Appengine backend for Android app, can a Python server handle a huge load?

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am building an Android app that I think has potential to reach 10 million users.

I realy like Python and I am not a huge fan of Java. The example application that Google has made for an appengine-backed Android project uses Java. I have only found Python libs for backends that are made by private people. Are these good enough?

Is there no official Google Python code for an Appengine GCM backend?

I don't want to start building something around technology that does not cut it.

Edit:
Even if Python is slower, maybe the programming language is not the bottleneck anyway?

Comment: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=java&data=u64

Comment: Those benchmarks are nonsense when it comes to web applications.  Unless the application is doing numerical intensive work (appengine isn't suited for it anyway), then the major time constraint is accessing things like the datastore, other services, instance startup time, and the performance of whatever templating environment you use.

Comment: Did you look at [Go](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/)? If you think that performance is very important, Go is a compiled language that should give you performance

Answer (score 3):

Python on App Engine can sustain the load as good as Java does, so o need to worry about scaling. (It will cost you though...)

Python on App Engine is very mature, well documented, and there are plenty of code libs, frameworks and examples. No problem in using Google Cloud Messaging, there is a RESTful API that you can use from python, see here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html